# Heap memory in java programming when merging a LONGBLOB object in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The stack is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hibernate.type.ByteArrayBlobType.deepCopy(ByteArrayBlobType.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.type.ByteArrayBlobType.replace(ByteArrayBlobType.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.replace(TypeFactory.java:538)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:704)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:228)
```

It is a bit difficult to make a huge amount of code to describe that problem, but i will try to explain what i have:

I have an object `A` that has a `foreign key` on an object `B` which is, in fact, an `xml` file that saved on `Mysql` db as `LONGBlob`.

So that error appreas when i try to `merge` (through `hibernate`) the object `A`.

I tried with changing memory parameters of the `JVM` on `eclipse` as:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

I wish i had explained my problem

Comment: Is your application running in tomcat container or only a java app?

Comment: On a java app running on elipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have adjusted Eclipse JVM memory settings (you are editing eclipse.ini file) not your application. You shall increase the heap size of your Java application in the Eclipse run configuration view.

And also you shall consider lazy loading entities (which is B in this case) that consume high memory resources.